# Why I get an unique error, if I have the values created on both table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I was doing a simple table connected to another which same date, and a get an error called:

> Unique constraint violated

I was reading about that, and said that is due to that there are some values on the father table. But I do some proof, and I don't think so, but I don't know...

The code is this:

```
CREATE TABLE articulo (codigo VARCHAR (8) CONSTRAINT articulo_codigo_pk PRIMARY KEY,
                       descripcion VARCHAR2(40),
                       dto REAL,
                       stock NUMBER(10),
                       stock_min NUMBER(10)
                       CHECK (dto LIKE '[30-70]'));


CREATE TABLE linea_ticket(ticket NUMBER(10),
                          nlinea VARCHAR(45) CONSTRAINT linea_ticket_nlinea_pk PRIMARY KEY,
                          cant NUMBER(10),
                          precio REAL,
                          dto NUMBER(2),
                          articulo VARCHAR2(8) CONSTRAINT linea_ticket_articulo_pg REFERENCES articulo(codigo)
                          );

INSERT INTO articulo (codigo, descripcion, dto, stock, stock_min)
    VALUES (5,'Producto tóxico', 30, 15,5);
INSERT INTO linea_ticket (ticket,nlinea,cant,precio,dto,articulo)
    VALUES (2,'LINEA2',1,30,30,5);
```

The point is although the "Articulo" and the "linea_ticket" share the same value on the tables, I get the error.

Comment: Do these CREATE TABLE really execute?

Comment: Is this Oracle?

Comment: `dto  LIKE '[30-70]'` is the same as `dto = '[30-70]'` but you can't compare a number with a varchar value

Comment: yesss to both questions

Comment: Unique Constraint is different from foreign key constraint violation. Are you trying to insert same values of primary key in any of these tables?

Comment: Okey, I found the problem. Definitely, I didn't have create on of those tables. Sorry for the inconviniences.

Comment: where is your foreign key (FK)?